# How to prevent concurrent INSERT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-insert, race-condition, data-consistency

During race condition, How to validate number of rows inserted to table A based on permitted row count defined in table B.

```
#Table A
CAMPAIGN_ID     ISSUE_LIMIT_PER_USER
-----------     --------------------
1000000111      1

#Table B
OFFER_ID    USER_ID     CAMPAIGN_ID   START_DATE  END_DATE
--------    -------     -----------   ----------  --------
11111111    90000       1000000111    2021-06-27  2021-07-27   Request1 allowed 
22222222    90000       1000000111    2021-06-28  2021-07-28   Request2 disallowed
33333333    90000       1000000111    2021-06-29  2021-07-29   Request3 disallowed
```

NOTE: There is no UNIQUE constraint in table B. Because we can have multiple rows based
on the value of ISSUE_LIMIT_PER_USER.

Requirement here is, how to prevent inserting more than 1 record (because ISSUE_LIMIT_PER_USER = 1) into table B when multiple parallel requests are made.

Below SQL I tried but not working.

```
INSERT INTO B(,,,,) SELECT (,,,,) FROM DUAL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(OFFER_ID) FROM B WHERE 
CAMPAIGN_ID=:campaign_id < :issue_limit_per_user
```

Because it is an INSERT query it can not lock anything and all parallel threads getting same count and finally inserting 1 row each. This solution works perfectly for other UPDATE use case.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is the following.

1. Create a new table with one row per campaign and per user.
2. Populate this table with the "used" limit from `A`.
3. Also have a column  which is the number of "used" rows.  Default the value to `0`.
4. Add a `check` constraint `used_issues <= issue_limit`.
5. Create a trigger on `B` to keep the value up-to-date for `insert`s, `delete`s, and `update`s.

Voila!  The limit will be verified by the `check` constraint.

Comment: If the option is to add trigger on B, why do we need new table ? Why can't that trigger validate the row count in table B with limit in A in INSERT ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumar . . . Because the limitation is *per user*.  Table `A` does not have a "user" column.

Comment: my point is a trigger after insert on B can count the number rows for the user_id, campaign_id combination and can validate against table A.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar . . . Not in Oracle.  you'll get a mutating table error.  The way I described might be the simplest solution.

Comment: … thank you for the solution, it helped me to see through a different window. I will be happy to understand the challenge with only trigger. It will be grate if you can help me to understand the mutating table error.

Comment: Now I understand- A trigger can not change a table that it has read from. This is the mutating table error issue.